# What's the difference between 'generic' and 'common'?

Tags: difference, adjectives, vocabulary

The two words both have the meaning that something is of the ordinary kind and not special. There are 2 examples (from Collins dictionary) following:

> 1. ...generic California apartments, the kind that have white walls and white drapes and were built five years ago.
> 2. Common salt is made up of 40% sodium and 60% chloride.

The question is what's the difference between them? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: _Common_ is a much more 'everyday' word than _generic_. Collins' first two definitions are the main meanings of the word _generic_; it says 'People _sometimes_ use generic to refer to something that is exactly typical of the kind of thing mentioned', but for most purposes you can ignore that definition.

Comment: Most people (in UK) won't know what you mean by "generic apartment" (although they might pretend to). You could say "typical apartment" if its style is the usual one for the locale.

Comment: "Common salt" is a relatively specialised technical usage. Lots of compounds are "salts", but "common salt" very specifically identifies ***sodium chloride*** (as opposed to, say, ***potassium chloride***, which tastes somewhat similar, and is used in "healthy" alternative seasonings such as [***Saxa So Low Reduced Sodium Salt***](https://www.ocado.com/products/saxa-so-low-reduced-sodium-salt-525109011?ds_rl=1290929&ds_rl=1291426&gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds)). But all the relevant nuances and differences can be established using online dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, but it's called 'common' because it's the ordinary sort that everyone has in their kitchen.

Comment: @KateBunting: In the *specific* case of "common salt" it's literally true that it's the ordinary sort that (nearly) everyone has in their kitchen. But there are many other examples of that same "relatively specialised technical usage" *(common **mint**, common **law**, common **time**, common **cold**,...)* where the fact of something being "the most prevalent variant" might not even be universally ***true***, let alone a "defining characteristic".

Comment: generic California apartment means: the usual California apartment. This comes from marketing: generic versus name brands. The generic London row house.